# SpringWS - Logging SoapRequest and SoapResponse in a table

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I have a SpringWS inplementation with below enpoint implementation

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace="http://college.com/schema/get_XML_Request/v2",localPart="get_XML_Request")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<GetStudentResponseType> handleStudentXML(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<GetStudentXMLRequestType> SoapRequest)throws Exception
        {

        String xmlResponse = "";

        com.college.get_student_xml_response.v2.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new com.company.schema.get_student_xml_response.v2.ObjectFactory();
        com.college.schema.get_student_xml_response.v2.GetResponseType resType = objectFactory.createGetResponseType();
        return objectFactory.createGetStudentResponse(resType);
        }
```

Here my objective is to log the request which coming to my webservice and response which the web service sent back in a table. Is it possible to get the SoapRequest/Soapresponse (In Soapformat) from the above method as a String.Here am able to get the payload, but i need to log with entire SoapRequest(with soapenvelope,body) Please anyone advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor.html) which logs the whole SOAP
Envelope including headers. So basically you can extend it to add the saving to the database functionality.

Comment: Thanks Carl, your ans really helped me to resolve some knots in my problem. Here again am struct with another problem like , i have to log the Req/Res in a db with a uniqueId(UID) which generating inside the endpoint class.Now, am able to log the request with this UID in Endpoint class, but for Response am not able to pass/get the UID which generated in the endpoint class, since the complete reponse(with soap header values) is available only in the interceptor after the scope is coming out from the Endpoint class. Please help to pass/use the object which generated in the Endpoint class.